# How to do a route with a modal with Expressjs?

Tags: node.js, express

Don't know where to start so don't have any code to post, how can I create  a dynamic route with expresss that shows a modal instead of a completely new page? (with the previous route on the background of the modal), I am using handlebars as the view engine.

Comment: essentially to open /login as route and on the background the page they clicked the login button from.

Comment: Why do you want to have a complete route for the modal. Just add some html containing the login form in your modal on the same page.

Comment: This has nothing to do with some special express feature. Addressing this issue deals exclusively with client-side code.

Comment: I just give a bad example of a login page, but I have a list of items on a page and when I open an item I want them to be opened in a modal with the item's details, I want this so people can link back to the specific item and it will open in a modal when they open the link: see producthunt for example...I wanted it server side rendered for the SEO benefits...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Assuming that you are using jQuery in your client's webpage:**

You probably have a button or something to trigger the opening of the modal. Add an event listener to this trigger and prevent the default event. Then send an ajax get request to your server. In your node application either send the data by rendering or by using `res.json()`.

```
$("#modalTrigger").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/theURL" // Modify the url according to your application logic
    }).done(function(yourData) {
        // Now open the modal! (Assuming you are using bootstrap.js)
        $("#yourModal").modal("show");
        // If you used 'res.json' then you can use yourData here
        $("#paragraphInModal").html(yourData);
    });
}
```

Comment: I ended up using a variation of your answer and when I open the modal I do  history.pushState to the url  item/id123 so reactive and when people go directly to that url  example item/id123 I just show it from the server in a page that automatically opens a modal and populare the data needed..so page won't refresh now if people click on it from the homepage and if they go directly to the item page it will load from the server